# Missing fonts on web pages

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I am trying to use a font on a webpage that does not exist natively on all the clients. Is there a way to detect that missing font and notify the user where to download it?

Comment: Why not just make it available for everyone using `@font-face`?

Comment: First of all I am trying to use a font that is blacklisted from fontsquirrel. I need it converted so that we could show the client how the site will be, and then we will buy the license. Secondly, I'd prefer those who downvote to leave a reply on why they downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way with `@font-face` is much more elegant, but here's solution if you want to notify the user (although I strongly suggest you take `@font-face`):

You could use a script like [FontChecker](https://github.com/darkwing/FontChecker) to check if a font is available. It relies on [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) and gets called like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
  var fc = new FontChecker();
  if (!fc.check('Some Font')) {
    alert('Please install "Some Font"!');
  }
});
```

If *Some Font* isn't available, a message appears.

If you don't use MooTools, there are similar scripts for other libraries or vanilla JS (=plain JS without libraries). Or just rewrite it, [it's quite short](https://github.com/darkwing/FontChecker/blob/master/Source/FontChecker.js).

Some other scripts (I don't know them, I only use FontChecker):

- jQuery: http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/
- Vanilla: http://www.samclarke.com/2013/06/javascript-is-font-available/
- Another vanilla: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: I believe this is what I want. I will accept you in a couple of minutes :) Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

If the font is licensed for use on a public webpage, you can just use `@font-face` as referenced in other answers here.

However, most commercial fonts are NOT licensed for web use, as anyone can just inspect your CSS and download the font for themselves, then.

Your best bet would be to select a different font from a service like google web fonts and use @font-face.

http://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: I am aware of that. I mostly want to detect if that font exists on the computer or not (without having to access files). For example (in question), I want to use cambria font which is native to the pc.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). But it's not pure CSS, it uses JS for creating canvas based fonts.